# What are the stories of Mhasoba and Khandoba?

Tags: scripture, temple, tradition

[Mhasoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mhasoba) and [Khandoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khandoba) are very popular Maharastrian deities. Their temples are popular pilgrim places.

What are their respective stories ?

Are they mentioned in any scriptures ?

Comment: Are they related deities? Otherwise it will be two distinct Qs in one.